# Routing In Simple PHP from Navigation Menu

Tags: php, url, routes, cakephp-routing

I have the root project-folder. Where each php files are in specific folder.
For each nav items, I have passed the php page through href="" tag. 
When I click on the nav item it then takes me to the requested page as passed in href. But when from that page if i choose other nav items it says page not found.

- Project
- Categories
  1. Page.php
  2. NextPage.php

- Extras
  1. extra.php

e.g
`<a href="Categories/page.php">Page</a>`
 `<a href="Extras/extra.php">Extra</a>`
When I am on extra.php and choose another nav items from navigation it says object not found. The URI becomes unreachable i.e `http://localhost/Project/Extras/extra.php/Categories/page.php`"Object Not Found" It should be like `http://localhost/Project/Categories/page.php`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use absolute links

```
<a href="/Project/Categories/page.php">Page</a> 
<a href="/Project/Extras/extra.php">Extra</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your tags start from the project root by prefixing all the links with `/`

`<a href="/Project/Categories/page.php">Page</a>`